# When is it permissible to abandon another Muslim?

Tags: halal-haram

As-Salamu alaikum brothers and sisters, I have a Muslim classmate that would everyday pick on me. If I speak to him he will mock me or do other mean things, and in class he humiliates me and make others laugh at me even when it isn't funny. Even in the lunch hall he'd play with the food and make tabzeer. And when I tell him to stop, he just ignores or mocks me. At this point, is it permissible for me to abandon him? If I don't he will continue doing haram things, but Allah knows best.
Edit: I'm not asking for interpersonal help, I'm just asking if it's halal to abandon a Muslim, because there was a Hadith that forbids, but in this case I'm abandoning a Muslim to stop him from doing haram.

Comment: what is a tabzeer, also has this person ever thrown something at you or hit you in anyway.

Comment: Yes, both hit and thrown. And tabzeer is wastage of materials.

Comment: I ansewered this but would like to know if you think this person would completely stop if you abandoned him. the way you describe him it does not seem like it

Comment: As-written, this really appears to be an interpersonal skills issue rather than anything to do with the topic of Islam. I am closing this for now; I recommend either focussing the question so it's clearly on topic here, or posting over at interpersonal.stackexchange.com .

Comment: goldPseuso brother or sister you misunderstood, I was asking if it was HALAL for me to abandon another Muslim. Because I heard of a Hadith that forbids us from abandoning a Muslim for more than three days. But I've been told that's it's haram to stay in bad company. Sorry for lack of clarity, I'll edit my question in shaa Allah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In the name of God, the Beneficent, the Most Just

**All praise and thanks are due to God, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in God from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever God guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but God, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**Your statement:** "I have a Muslim classmate that would everyday pick on me. If I speak to him he will mock me or do other mean things, and in class he humiliates me and make others laugh at me even when it isn't funny. Even in the lunch hall he'd play with the food and make tabzeer. And when I tell him to stop, he just ignores or mocks me. At this point, is it permissible for me to abandon him? If I don't he will continue doing haram things, but Allah knows best." is wrong, you should not abandon him just because he has done this, for it is a major sin to do that unless you abandon him for good, then yes it is a major sin.

**Answer:** I'm sorry to hear this. Have you tried to talk to him and ask him why is she doing this to you? Have you tried to ask teacher's help for this or your parents's help? it is a grave sin to abandon another Muslim.

Abandoning one’s fellow Muslims is a grave major sin if it lasts for more than three days, and if it is not for a shariah-approved reason as this leads to the severing of relations as well as harm and corruption. This is supported by many narrations like that one on the authority of Abu Ayyoob Al-Ansaari, may Allah be pleased with him, where the Prophet ( may  Allah exalt his mention ) said: **“It is not lawful for a Muslim to abandon his brother for more than three nights [such that], when they meet, they turn their backs to each other - and the better of the two is the one who is the first to greet the other.”** [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

In a narration on the authority of Abu Hurayrah, may Allah be pleased with him, the Prophet ( may  Allah exalt his mention ) said: **“It is not lawful for a Muslim to abandon his Muslim brother for more than three days; and whoever does so and then dies, will enter Hell.”** [Abu Daawood, Al-Albaani - Hasan]

Have you tried to advise him to stop? In Islam, it is prohibited to mock others based on what Allah The Almighty Says (what means): **{O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another] people; perhaps they may be better than them.}** [Quran 49:11]

Don't worry, because at the end of the day, on the day of judgment, those who are mocked at will mock at those criminals while enjoying luxuries beyond what Dunya would offer them. They will sit back, relax, enjoy things that they love doing with the best quality of materials and, above all, they will enjoy the fate of those criminals and will pity them, seeing them experience what the Lord decided what they best deserve – the Hell-fire. This is what is written for them.

If your class mate ignores you, that is due to Satan as the following narration:

> It was narrated that Jabir ibn ‘Abd-Allah (may Allah be pleased with him) said: I heard the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Satan has despaired of being worshipped by the worshippers in the Arabian Peninsula, but his aim is to create troubles among them.”

Hence Allah has forbidden everything that may lead to enmity and resentment among the Muslims. Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> “Satan wants only to incite enmity and hatred between you with intoxicants (alcoholic drinks) and gambling, and hinder you from the remembrance of Allah and from the prayer. So, will you not then abstain?” [5:91]

I have found a list which might help you in this kind of situation:

1. [**Do not mock, backbit or lie about others**](https://www.islamicity.org/4242/do-not-mock-backbit-or-lie-about-others/)
2. [**Khutbah by Nouman Ali Khan: Mocking Others and Arrogance**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rPh3qIPnx2w)
3. [**Worship in Islam: An In-Depth Study of Ibadah, Salah and Sawm**](https://books.google.ro/books?id=Yk0xCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=what+will+happen+to+those+who+mock+others?+in+Islam&source=bl&ots=7_8o0gfAhz&sig=ACfU3U3UpqBJ5obC1lRmTauvOnllyqK3pQ&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKhpHJidfiAhUstIsKHfCVCCcQ6AEwEnoECAoQAQ)

The Noble Prophet (S) said:

> “If a person humiliates a believer, indigent or otherwise, Allah shall always abhor and humiliate him.”

Allah Says:

> "And it has already come down to you in the Book that when you hear the verses of Allah [recited], they are denied [by them] and ridiculed; so do not sit with them until they enter into another conversation. Indeed, you would then be like them. Indeed Allah will gather the hypocrites and disbelievers in Hell all together" [[**The Women, 4:140**](https://quran.com/4/140)]

But if your class mate does not stop committing the sin, then you must leave him for 3 days, but it is better to explain to (the sinner) the reason for leaving, if that will have an effect on him and prompt him to give up the evil action.

---

**References:**

1. [**Abandonment - I**](https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/184711/abandonment-i)
2. [**Ignoring a Person Who Offends You 100 Times**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/126918/ignoring-a-person-who-offends-you-100-times)
3. [**25. Humiliation**](https://www.al-islam.org/anecdotes-reflection-part-2-sayyid-ali-akbar-sadaaqat/25-humiliation)
4. [**She has friends who are openly committing sin – should she continue to be friends with them?**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/21918/she-has-friends-who-are-openly-committing-sin-should-she-continue-to-be-friends-with-them)

Comment: The vast majority of this answer has nothing whatsoever to do with the topic of Islam and just dismisses the *actual* question asked. We are not interpersonal.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @goldPseudo What? Does that mean I have wasted all my effort?! I have tried to answer according to his question.

Comment: @AlexA, I only skim read but I think he/she means that you have not addressed whether this person is allowed to abandon his brother

Comment: @AsanRamzan Aaaa, well... in that case, I have not found any clear evidence that one should abandon a Muslim, I only find that another Muslim should advice another Muslim, or to go against the Muslim transgressor as a warning sign. If non has worked, then he may leave him.

Comment: @AlexA, in islam there are certain thing that Allah has commanded to be joined, including the Muslims, to severe these is going against the commad of Allah 13:25, Also every Muslim has certain right over his brother e.g. to return salaam. You have not reference this idea of  leaving his brother from the Quran. I only have heard one hadith where you can do such a thing but only for 3 days.